# Office 365 get contactperson id

Tags: office365

I need to know what the id of a contact person in `Office 365` but I can't find any documentation on how to do this. Is there anyone here who has any ideas on how to get this?

Any suggestions are welcome since I don't have a clue at the moment.

Comment: Hi Chard - Is your question re: contacts in Outlook accessed using Office 365 REST API for Contacts (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn792115(v=office.15).aspx)?  Or about users in a company Directory accessed using Azure AD APIs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn130116.aspx)?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my question was to Gravinco, not Chard.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey Venkat, I think it's REST but I'm not sure. How can I check this?

Comment: Hi Gravinco - Are you hitting a URL such as https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts?

Comment: Hey Venkat, sorry for the late response but my weekend was extremely chaotic. The URL I get when I go to my contacts page in Office365 is https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=mycompany.onmicrosoft.com#path=/people